# Guessing/extracting from the pool of partially right guesses

Tags: dataset, information-extraction

Lets assume that I have integer numbers from 1 to 50.

I imagine any 5 unique numbers from 1 to 50.

A computer can generate an array of 5 random numbers, as many times as it wants.
Each time it generates an array, it guesses 0, 1, or 2 numbers correctly.
There is an equal chance of obtaining 0, 1 or 2 guesses right.
It never guesses more than 2 numbers right.

If, lets say, computer generates a lot of guesses (lets say that lot means 1000), it will guess each number from the ones I imagined, at least once.
However, computer does not know which numbers are correct from the ones it guessed.

What would be the best method to apply to a pool of guesses to extract 5 numbers that would match the ones I imagined, in any order ?

Thanks!

EDIT (the source code for generating the pool of guesses)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;  

public class theGuessing {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    ArrayList<String> poolOfGuesses = new ArrayList<String>();
    int[] imagined = {2,4,5,30,48}; //these are the numbers I imagined.

    //now, let us create a pool of guesses, lets say there are 1000 guesses in a pool
    while(poolOfGuesses.size()<1000){
    //this is how one guess is generated:
    ArrayList<Integer> guess = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int numberOfCorrectNumbers = rnd.nextInt(3);
    while(guess.size() < numberOfCorrectNumbers){
        int correctNumberPosition = rnd.nextInt(imagined.length);
        int correctNumber = imagined[correctNumberPosition];
        if(!guess.contains(correctNumber)){guess.add(correctNumber);}
    }

    while(guess.size() < 5){
        int someRandomNumber = rnd.nextInt(50)+1;
        if(!guess.contains(someRandomNumber)){guess.add(someRandomNumber);}
    }

    //since the order does not matter, lets sort the Integer.
    Integer[] tosort = guess.toArray(new Integer[guess.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(tosort);

    //now, for fun lets make the guess a String
    String theGuess = "";
    for(Integer r:tosort){
        theGuess = theGuess+r+",";
    }

    theGuess = theGuess.substring(0, theGuess.length()-1); //removes the dangling comma
    //since we want a pool of guesses, just add theGuess to the pool
    poolOfGuesses.add(theGuess);
    }
}
```

What happens next, a person is given this poolOfGuesses and they need to find out, to best of their ability, what are the 5 numbers that I guessed. How would they do that ? what would be the best procedure ???

Comment: (1) This situation is impossible if the computer is truly guessing.  What mechanism is operating to limit the numbers of correct guesses and to assure equal chances of 0, 1, or 2 correct?  (2) There is no solution unless some information is associated with each guess, such as the count of correct ones. Exactly what information is available (besides the guesses themselves)?

Comment: Lets say that it randomly adds 0, 1 or 2 numbers from the ones I imagined just to make the "guessing" possible. This is not about how the pool is generated but about extracting the data from the pool. I have made up this hypothetical situation to be able to ask clearly about the type of a problem I would like to solve. There is no other information available, except for knowing that 0, 1 or 2 numbers in each array of data is right.

Comment: Unfortunately the details matter.  The actual chances of correct guesses how those guesses are correlated, and the specifics of how guesses are generated all determine what the "best method" will be.

Comment: Generate the "guesses" by selecting 0,1 or 2 numbers from the ones I imagined, randomly, and then by adding other random (and unique) integers from 1 to 50. Would you like the source code for a guessing part?

Comment: Just to make sure, here's what your algorithm sounds like. In each step, a *guesser* privately examines your five numbers. It draws a value $n$ from $\{0,1,2\}$, each equally likely. It then selects an $n$-subset of your numbers randomly, together with a $5-n$-subset of the other $45$ numbers, also randomly. These five numbers, together with $n$, are reported to a second person. This person is tasked with determining your five numbers based on a sequence of these steps. Do they have to make such a determination at each step? Or are they given all the steps at once and asked for an answer?

Comment: @whuber it would be much easier for me to write a program for generating the "guesses". Thank you for helping me out, I will edit my post with a source code.

Comment: @whuber please see the source code above.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the program always guesses 0, 1, or 2 numbers correct with equal probability the solution is straightforward. The numbers that occur with highest frequency after 1000 guesses are your best bet.

Example by R simulation

```
# number of guesses
n = 1e3 
# sample true values
true = sample(1:50, 5)
# empty matrix to store guesses
guess = matrix(NA, n, 5)
for (i in 1:n) {
  # sample how many are guess correctly
  right = sample(0:2, 1)
  # make guess
  guess[i, ] = c(sample(true, right), sample((1:50)[-true], 5L - right))
}
# get frequency with which every number is guessed
tb = table(c(guess))
plot(tb, las = 1, bty = 'n', col = ifelse(1:50 %in% true, 'gold', 'black'))
```

[image: Frequency Plot]

Proof by math.

Since $P(A) = \sum_i P(A|B_i)*P(B_i)$ the probability of a guess $g$ being any correct number $c$ is:

\begin{align}
P(g=c) &= P(g=c|\text{2 correct guesses})*P(\text{2 correct guesses}) + \\
& \quad P(g=c|\text{1 correct guesses})*P(\text{1 correct guesses}) + \\
& \quad P(g=c|\text{0 correct guesses})*P(\text{0 correct guesses}) \\
& = \frac{1}{3} (\frac{2}{5} + \frac{1}{5} + 0) =  \frac{1}{5}
\end{align}

To get the probability for an individual true number to be guessed we have to further divide this by the amount of correct numbers. The probability for a correct number to be guessed is then $\frac{\frac{1}{5}}{5} = \frac{1}{25} = 0.04$. The probability for a false number to be guessed is $1-\frac{1}{5} = \frac{4}{5}$. However, we also have to divide this by the number of options, resulting in $\frac{\frac{4}{5}}{45} = \frac{4}{225} \approx 0.01778$. Since the probability for a true number to be guessed is much larger, the best strategy is to choose the numbers that appear with highest frequency after 1000 guesses.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting answer, I was wondering, since after getting more than 1000 results and then getting a frequency you can extract one answer. Would it have any meaning to repeat the same frequency extraction more than 1000 times to get even better results ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you divide the number of observations of a single guess by the total number of guesses you will see get the observed proportion; a decimal number that should approach either 0.01778 or 0.04. With a small number of results these proportions will be pretty variable, but if the number of results increases the proportions will get closer to the theoretical values. So repeating the same extraction to more than 1000 times will improve the results.

Comment: Actually, it would not improve the results. I have tested it and it did not work at all. There was no improvement simply because the results were randomly generated. There has to be some kind of a learning algorithm involved, if any.